# Spotify on Ubuntu 20.04 Local files crashes

Tags: 20.04, spotify

When I try to add a source on Spotify in the local files section the whole program just crashes. It did the same on Pop!_OS and I remember on Manjaro it opened a really old UI with broken fonts of a file browser. Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks

Comment: Hey rover000! Which Ubuntu version are you using and which version of the Spotify app are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu version: 20.04

Spotify version: 1.1.42.622.gbd112320 @technastic_tc

Comment: How did you download Spotify? Is it using the 'Ubuntu Software' app?

Comment: Yes @technastic_tc

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling and check if the issue persists?

Comment: Same happens here on 20.04 and 20.10 Ubuntu. Spotify 1.1.4.622 just bluntly crashes when start up (i965 fatal error ) . For now I just use their webplayer, as nothing helps or works.